# Duvida como tirar, no NetBeans, o fundo quando seleciona uma palavra?

Tags: netbeans

[image: esse fundo em amarelo que eu quero tirar]

No NetBeans estou tendo um problema, quando seleciono uma palavra, ela fica com essa marcação com uma cor desagradável. Ficaria bonito se mudasse para azul, como acontece quando programo em JavaFX, mas quando programo em C++ esse fundo fica amarelo claro... como mudar?

Comment: Da uma olhada em Ferramentas > Opções > Fonts & Cores > Sintaxe > Linguagem C++ > categoria Identificador.

Comment: Não Resolveu o problema :(

Comment: Ferramentas -> Opções -> Fontes & Cores -> Realce -> Texto Selecionado... bom proveito

Comment: Descobriu a solução amigo? Estou com o mesmo problema